# Simulate a text input change as if the user had typed a specific key in order to trigger React's onChange handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, input, react-hooks

I'm using the `onKeyDown` handler to prevent the user from adding more than 1 `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` (which is "." in this example) into an input field.

And that is working as you can see from the GIF below.

But I would like to accept the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` (which is "," in the example), as if the user had typed the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR`.

In other words, if the user hits `15` and then hits the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`, I would like to convert it into a `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR`.

Note: I don't want to replace the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` in the value string, because at some point there might be other `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`s present in the string and it would get tricky.

**QUESTION**

Is is possible for me to simulate a `keyPress, keyDown, onChange ???` event for the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` key from my `else` block from the snippet below?

Basically what I want is: "Prevent default on the event for the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` (which I'm already doing) and I should create an event that should behave exactly like as if the user had typed the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` key".

How can I do it?

```js
const DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ".";
const THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ",";

function App() {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  
  function onChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(newValue);
  }

  function onKeyDown(event) {
    console.log("onKeyDown...");
    if (event.key === DECIMAL_SEPARATOR || event.key === THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) {
      const currentValue = event.target.value;
      // PREVENTS USER OF ENTERING MORE THAN ONE DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
      if (currentValue === "" || currentValue.indexOf(DECIMAL_SEPARATOR) >= 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        // AT THIS POINT I WOULD LIKE TO CONVERT THE THOUSAND_SEPARATOR INTO DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
      }
    }
  }

  return(
    <input 
      type="text"
      onChange={onChange}
      onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**Here is what happens now:**

[image]

Comment: hi there! so you want to assign a DECIMAL_SEPARATOR value to THOUSAND_SEPARATOR right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to "change" what the user has typed for that situation.

Comment: ok got it, give me a minute...

Comment: change const THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  to let, as you want to change the value, assign event.key value to it... but it triggers only if  key matches '.' or ',' so if you don't want that than you can change your conditional statement.

Comment: jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/abyus873/

Comment: got it, let me know if you need any more help.!

Comment: @LakshmanKambam not working. I don't know if I wasn't completely clear. But I don't mean to change the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` value. I need it to replace the result on the screen, as if the user had typed the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` instead of the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`

Comment: ok you want whatever the user types except '.' or I don't understand can you clarify?

Comment: The situation I want to handle is: 1. The user has typed "," (which is the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`). 2. I will call `preventDefault()` (this is already done in the code). 3. I wan't to dispatch some even as if the user had typed the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` which is "." (point). Thanks

Comment: Have you thought to use a regex or two to validate/fix input instead?

Comment: @cbdeveloper hm ok, let me update jsfiddle that I shared with you. give me a minute....

Comment: @DrewReese yes, but I figured it would be more complicated. But I will give it a try.

Comment: @DrewReese you're right. also Intl.NumberFormat provided locales that are supported without having to fall back to the runtime's default locale. so you can just change currency format by providing options like { style: "currency", currency: "INR" }. pretty simple.

Comment: What if the user *want's* to type "15,000"? How will your logic determine the user's intent *after* it forces the "," to "." when the user gets to "15,"? I don't think it can. It may be better to let a user enter any number they please and *then* do input validation and formatting to insert localized decimal and grouping separators.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: @DrewReese something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-number-format-pr1j9

Comment: @cbdeveloper also you need to edit/update your question title and description as it's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm suggesting solution in a way I like/think very simple. as we developers know that we can solve one problem in many different ways as per our use cases. I hope I'm helpful and cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not currency format that you want than you can do it like

```
function numberFormat(num) {
   return num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}
console.log(numberFormat(5000)); // 5,000.00
```

and you can decide if you want `.` or `,` by changing `$1,` or `$1.` here

`num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')`

Simple way to do currency format is using the JavaScript Internationalization API and it is dynamic.

The `Intl.NumberFormat` object is a constructor for objects that enable language sensitive number formatting.

```
function App() {
    let [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    function onChange(event) {
        let value = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format((event.target.value).replace(/\D+/g, ""));
        setInputValue(value === '0' ? '' : value);
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" onChange={onChange} value={inputValue} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

replace with empty string if not number

`(event.target.value).replace(/\D+/g, "")`

[check working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-p1889)

This is in USD, however.

Different countries have different conventions to display values.

JavaScript makes it very easy for us with the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), a relatively recent browser API that provides a lot of internationalization features, like dates and time formatting.

It is very well supported:

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
})

formatter.format(1000) // "$1,000.00"
formatter.format(10) // "$10.00"
formatter.format(123233000) // "$123,233,000.00"
```

The `minimumFractionDigits` property sets the fraction part to be always at least 2 digits. You can check which other parameters you can use in the [NumberFormat MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

This example creates a number formatter for the Euro currency, for the Italian country:

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('it-IT', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Lakshman. I know there are other ways around my problem, but I found out a way to do exactly what I wanted. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135

It seems that what I need is not possible. I was able to trigger the `onChange` method by dispatching a `change` event by doing this (suggested in the issue):

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === ",") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const previousValue = input_ref.current.value;
      const caretPosition = input_ref.current.selectionStart;
      const point = ".";
      const newValue = [previousValue.slice(0, caretPosition), point, previousValue.slice(caretPosition)].join('');

      input_ref.current.value = newValue;

      const tracker = input_ref.current._valueTracker;

      if (tracker) {
        tracker.setValue(previousValue);
      }

      input_ref.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
    }
  }
```

This indeed triggers the `onChange` event. But you get a caret jump. So, it's not **exactly as if the user had typed the key**. You end up hard-changing the input value and get a caret jump anyway.

So I've ended up doing this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-forest-1e3g3

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ".";
const THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ",";

export default function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const input_ref = useRef(null);

  function __setCaretPosition(caretPos) {
    if (input_ref.current.createTextRange) {
      var range = input_ref.current.createTextRange();
      range.move("character", caretPos);
      range.select();
    } else {
      if (input_ref.current.selectionStart) {
        input_ref.current.focus();
        input_ref.current.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
      } else {
        input_ref.current.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  function onChange(event, moveCaret = false) {
    console.log("From onChange...");
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    const caretPosition = input_ref.current.selectionStart;

    setInputValue(newValue);

    __setCaretPosition(caretPosition + (moveCaret ? 1 : 0));

    setTimeout(() => {
      __setCaretPosition(caretPosition + (moveCaret ? 1 : 0));
    }, 0);
  }

  function onKeyDown(event) {
    console.log("From onKeyDown...");
    const inputValue = input_ref.current.value;
    const caretPosition = input_ref.current.selectionStart;
    if (event.key === THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const fakeEvent = {
        target: {
          value: [
            inputValue.slice(0, caretPosition),
            DECIMAL_SEPARATOR,
            inputValue.slice(caretPosition)
          ].join("")
        }
      };
      const moveCaret = true;
      onChange(fakeEvent, moveCaret);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        ref={input_ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```